# How to show that the quotient norm is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $(E, \lVert\bullet\rVert)$ is a normed vector space and $M$ a linear subspace that is closed we can define a norm on the quotient space $E/M$ by $\lVert x+M\rVert = \inf\limits_{m\in M} \lVert x+m\rVert$.

How do we know that $\lVert x+M\rVert<\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's pretty clear that
$$\inf_{m\in M}\|x+m\|\le\|x\|.$$